# How to Load SSL Certificate and Private Key into Java KeyStore for HTTP POST with Apache HTTP Client?

Tags: java, spring-boot, openssl, ssl-certificate, sslcontext

I have a certificate file (.crt) and a private key file. I need to programmatically load these files into a Java `KeyStore` and use them to make secure HTTP POST requests using Apache's HTTP Client.

- Certificate Format: My certificate is encoded with the typical 'BEGIN CERTIFICATE' followed by a Base64 encoded string.
- Private Key Format: My private key is encoded with 'BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY' and then another Base64 encoded string.

I've searched for solutions, but most of them either point to external tools or don't fit my specific use case.

this is how i am trying but not worked

```
        KeyStore KeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        keyStore.load(null, null);
        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("keyStore.jks"))
        {
            keyStore.store(fos, null);
        }

        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        ks.load(new FileInputStream("keyStore.jks"), null);

        byte[] data = amazonS3Configuration
                .downloadFile(KeyFilePath + "/"
                        + CertificatePath);
        ByteArrayInputStream targetStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
        Certificate certificate =
                CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509").generateCertificate(targetStream);
        ks.setCertificateEntry("clientCertificate", certificate);
        ks.store(new FileOutputStream("keyStore.jks"), null);
        
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

        //storing private key
        byte[] privateKeyData = amazonS3Configuration
                .downloadFile(soapKeyFilePath + "/"
                        + KeyFilePath);

        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA","BC");
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec privateKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privateKeyData);
        PrivateKey privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec);
        System.out.println("Private Key: " + privateKey);
        ks.setKeyEntry("privateKey", privateKey, null, null);
```

I'm looking for guidance or code examples on how to:

1. Load the certificate and private key from files into a Java `KeyStore`.
2. Set up an `SSLContext` for secure communication.
3. Use Apache's HTTP Client to make HTTP POST requests using this `SSL Context`.

Comment: "Not worked" is not a problem description.

Comment: It throwing this error                                                                                                                                                                                       
    
    
    
    
    
 org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.util.ExtendedInvalidKeySpecException: unable to process key spec: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: failed to construct sequence from byte[]: unknown tag 13 encountered